# Horizontal Flatlist with vertical headers

Tags: react-native, scrollview

How to have a horizontal flatlist with fixed horizontal and vertical headers.

This picture might help you understand my question better [FlatList in ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OctN5.png)

I tried to move FlatList to ScrollView, which enabled me to have a left header visible all the time, but I cannot make top header visible all the time as when user scroll down the top headers go offscreen. Is there a way to stick them on top. Unlike left headers, top headers are different for each entry, so I cannot make it part of ScrollView.

```
return (
<ScrollView style={{flex:1}}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    {this.renderVerticalHeader()}
    <View style={{ flexGrow: 1}}>
         <FlatList
             data={flatListContents}
             horizontal={true}
             contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow:1}}
             centerContent={true}
             renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
              <View>{item}</View>
              )}}/>
         </View>
   </ScrollView>
);
```

FlatList contents are rendered as:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, width: 500 }} onPress={() => this.onPressAction()} >
            <Text>
                {this.renderHeader()}
            </Text>
            <ScrollView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            >
                {this.renderBody()}
            </ScrollView>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

I want FlatList header to be visible all the time, which hides when I scroll down.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: Could you mention the scroll axis for both ScrollView and FlatList in the attached picture?

Comment: Thanks! I have added sample code to my question. @HunaidHassan ScrollView is vertical scroll and Flatlist is horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thanks @jocactus, I have added sample code to my question.

Comment: There is a prop called `stickyHeaderIndices` in ScrollView. Can you make use of it?

Comment: @HunaidHassan how? Top level scrollList doesn't have indices of the scrollList that is within Flatlist. Can you post your solution and I can try it?

Comment: I don't really have a solution because I never ran into such scenario. Can you quickly put together a working Expo example to demonstrate the issue. I will be in better position to help then.